# How do I copy the strings of an entire Listview to my clipboard in delphi?

Tags: listview, delphi, clipboard

I want to copy all rows and columns into my clipboard from a listview. I tried using `Clipboard.Astext := SavedDataLb.Items.Text` but that obviously doesn't work because Listviews dont have a `Text` property. I also thought about using a built-in `CopyToClipboard` function from the ListView, but that unfortunately doesn't exist either. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to write your own function which, for a VCL list view, might look something list this:

```
procedure ListViewCopyToClipboard(ListView: TListView);
// Copy the list view contents to the clipboard, as text with one tab-delimited line per row.

  function ReplaceString(const s, Old, New: string): string;
  begin
    Result := StringReplace(s, Old, New, [rfReplaceAll]);
  end;

  procedure AddString(Strings: TStringList; s: string);
  begin
    // Ensure we get one line per row by by replacing any cr's & lf's with spaces.
    s := ReplaceString(s, sLineBreak, ' ');
    s := ReplaceString(s, #13, ' ');
    s := ReplaceString(s, #10, ' ');
    Strings.Add(s);
  end;

  function GetHeaderCaptionsAsString: string;
  var
    Col: Integer;
  begin
    Assert(ListView.ViewStyle=vsReport);
    Result := '';
    for Col := 0 to ListView.Columns.Count-1 do begin
      Result := Result + ListView.Columns[Col].Caption;
      if Col<ListView.Columns.Count-1 then begin
        Result := Result + #9;
      end;
    end;
  end;

  function GetItemAsString(Row: Integer): string;
  var
    Index: Integer;
    Item: TListItem;
  begin
    Item := ListView.Items[Row];
    Result := Item.Caption;
    for Index := 0 to Item.SubItems.Count-1 do begin
      Result := Result + #9 + Item.SubItems[Index];
    end;
  end;

var
  Row: Integer;
  OutputAll: Boolean;
  Strings: TStringList;

begin
  Strings := TStringList.Create;
  try
    if ListView.ViewStyle=vsReport then begin
      AddString(Strings, GetHeaderCaptionsAsString);
    end;
    OutputAll := not ListView.MultiSelect or (ListView.SelCount=0);
    for Row := 0 to ListView.Items.Count-1 do begin
      if OutputAll or ListView.Items[Row].Selected then begin
        AddString(Strings, GetItemAsString(Row));
      end;
    end;
    Clipboard.AsText := Strings.Text;
  finally
    FreeAndNil(Strings);
  end;
end;
```

Comment: It doesn't need any explanation. The function and variable names make it clear what everything is doing.

Comment: This worked perfect and was, like David said, pretty self explainatory, but in order for it to work I had to add `index:= 0` in `GetItemAsString` under the `begin`.

Comment: @FinnAndreWorm That doesn't solve the problem. You'll just get the first row over and over again. I've corrected the mistake in an edit. Please refresh to see. I made the mistake because I hacked the code out of another location where it didn't look quite like this, and made a mistake in the process.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan ah yes, youre right. I thought It worked because I kept on saving the same values in it over and over again for my own comfort. Works perfect now. Thank you.